# How to prevent Kendo UI Grid from rebinding after data.set("somefield","something");

Tags: kendo-grid

I'm updating cell value this way

```
var grid = $("#OrderGrid").data("kendoGrid"); 
var select = grid.select();
var dataItem = grid.dataItem(select);
dataItem.set("OrderStatusCodeName","AA");
```

this is rebinding grid. so I want to stop the databind event after data.set

I also tried the code written below:

```
dataItem["OrderStatusCodeName"] = status;

dataItem.OrderStatusCodeName = status;
```

the above code is not working.